# Create/configure New repository in remote mercurial server on IIS

Tags: iis, version-control, mercurial

Are there any tools avaliable to create and configure (Add new users, Change authorization settings ) mercurial repository hosted in IIS server ? 
Currently I want to remotely log in to the server and need to create new repository and configure it manually.

Comment: Jayantha: could you use my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Kallithea](http://kallithea-scm.org/). That is a like a [hgweb](http://selenic.com/hg) on steriods :) It has user management with authentication against LDAP (so you can use Active Directory), repository management, browsing, etc.

You ask about IIS and I know that it can run Python WSGI applications. Kallithea is based on Pylons and while it's described a difficult, you *can* [run Pylons on IIS](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Serving+a+Pylons+app+with+IIS) if you want.

I would probably install Apache instead or simply use the small web server that comes with Kallithea (depending on the load you expect).